# AX Form Grid selection

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics

I have created a custom form with a grid that diplays data from a TempDB table. The grid is used to print out reports based on which lines are selected, and the user can specify the report quantity for each line through a field in the grid.

However, when the quantity value is changed, the grid loses the line selections. Is there a way to retain the grid selections even while changing a value in a grid field?

Answer (score 0):

You can add extra column (eg. `Selected`) and hide standard selection checkbox (`ShowRowLabels = No`)

Comment: Absolutely, and that would be a solution if it is not possible to do it with the standard selection. However, there seems to be little information regarding such methods. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the grid is losing the line selections is most likely your custom code. If you call `YourFormDataSource.executeQuery()` for example, it will lose the selection.

The solution is to modify your code to retain the marked records before calling an action that clears the marked records.  You can do this like follows:

```
Array           markedRecords;

// This stores the marked records in an array
markedRecords = SalesTable_ds.recordsMarked();

// The behavior of this clears the marked records
SalesTable_ds.executeQuery();

// This sets the marked records back
SalesTable_ds.markRecords(markedRecords);
```

You should be aware though, that the marked records are basically a row number of the current order of the grid. So if the user sorts a column, that changes the original query.  So when you call `executeQuery()` it will sort it using the original `query` and mark the rows based on that.

You should identify what in your code is clearing the selections and see if this method alone will solve it, or if you need to do additional customization to track the marked records...or if you can prevent them from becoming unmarked in the first place.

You can see how a user sorting the query changes the run-time query by something like this:

```
// Sort the grid manually before calling this code
info(strFmt("%1", SalesTable_ds.queryRun().toString()));
SalesTable_ds.executeQuery();
info(strFmt("%1", SalesTable_ds.queryRun().toString()));
```

And the output will be something like:

> Query  object 236eb5a0: SELECT FIRSTFAST * FROM SalesTable(SalesTable) ORDER BY SalesTable.CustAccount ASC
>
> Query  object 236ebe98: SELECT FIRSTFAST * FROM SalesTable(SalesTable) USING INDEX SalesIdx

Here is a secondary method to use if your `query` or records are changing. This is more reliable and is likely what you'll want to use:

```
SalesTable          salesTableLocal;
RecordLinkList      rll = new RecordLinkList();

for (salesTableLocal = SalesTable_ds.getFirst(true); salesTableLocal; salesTableLocal = SalesTable_ds.getNext())
{
    rll.ins(salesTableLocal);
}

SalesTable_ds.executeQuery();

while (rll.next(salesTableLocal))
{
    SalesTable_ds.markRecord(salesTableLocal, 1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a shot and get back to with my results.